# How could I send the information in AJAX at POST?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Sorry for my english...

How could I send the information that's in Ajax with POST? (`info`, `info_1`, `info_2`)

Now, I'm sending it with GET

**edit:**  i try to do what people here said me to do, but when i call the POST variable in the page that i send for him the info, its show me eror... why?

*the new code:*

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST",url,true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if( this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById(name).innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
};
xhr.send("info="+str+"&info_1="+info_1+"&info_2="+info_2);
return false;
```

---

*the first code:*

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET",url+"?info="+str+"&info_1="+info_1+"&info_2="+info_2,true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if( this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById(name).innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
};
xhr.send();
return false;
```

Comment: Consider using jquery for that or any other library with ajax tools...

Comment: What kind of error? Are you sending a post request to an addrress other than yours? If yes, then check [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: @GauravSharma No, it shows me that the POST variable does not exist

Answer (score 1):

Change `"GET"` to `"POST"` and put the data (in the same form as in the query string, but without the `?` prefix) as the argument to the `send()` method instead of in the URL.

Comment: I think the OP would do well with an example, he already stated his English is not great.

Comment: @Quentin i dont know y its not works for me... when i call the post variable its show me eror

Answer (score 1):

I used this code. It worked

```
function getXMLHttpRequestObject()
{
  var xmlhttp;
  if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
    try {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
      xmlhttp = false;
    }
  }
  return xmlhttp;
}
function callme1(){
var http = new getXMLHttpRequestObject();

var url = "yourpage.php";
var reply;
var conf=true;
var parameters = "info="+str+"&info_1="+info_1+"&info_2="+info_2;
http.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", parameters .length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(http.readyState == 4) {
        alert(http.responseText);   
    }
}
http.send(parameters);
}
```

Just call function `callme1()` and it will post the request to `yourpage.php`

Answer (score 0):

This is how to send Post request in ajax

```
var str="hrl";// initialize str
var info_1="hi"; // initialize info_1
var info_2="hi"; // initialize info_2
var url="index.jsp"; // initialize url
var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);// initialize url
xmlhttp.send("info="+ str +"&info_1="+ info_1 +"&info_2="+info_2+"");
```